# How could I reverse the click event in javascript

Tags: javascript, events

How could I reverse on click event to initial position?

well, I want to change the x icon to + icon by click, which I made it but how could I reverse that?
i tried MOUSEUP and DBLCLICK which they are not good options, and if i use CLICK event in =>firstLiI.addEventListener('click', start2);  it override the first logic.

```
const firstLiI = document.querySelector('li').children[0].children[0];

firstLiI.addEventListener('click', start1);
firstLiI.addEventListener('dblclick', start2);

//Event Handler
function start1(){
  firstLiI.classList.add('fa-plus');
  firstLiI.classList.remove('fa-remove');
}

function start2(){
  firstLiI.classList.remove('fa-plus');
  firstLiI.classList.add('fa-remove');

}
```

Comment: you want to display x if you have + and + if you have x ? did i understand you correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

You should `toggle` classes:

```
const firstLiI = document.querySelector('li').children[0].children[0];

firstLiI.addEventListener('click', start1);

//Event Handler
function start1(){
  firstLiI.classList.toggle('fa-plus');
  firstLiI.classList.toggle('fa-remove');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `button` without `fa-plus` or `fa-remove` icons ( just button with a placeholder text ) your first click should add `fa-plus` then you need to apply logic as below to toggle icons.

(If you want to reverse this situation you need to change `.add` to `.remove` and `.remove` to `.add`. that's all.)

```
const firstLiI = document.querySelector('li').children[0].children[0];

firstLiI.addEventListener('click', start);

//Event Handler
function start(){!firstLiI.classList.contains('fa-plus')} {
if ( 
  firstLiI.classList.add('fa-plus');
  firstLiI.classList.remove('fa-remove');
}
else if {
  firstLiI.classList.remove('fa-plus');
  firstLiI.classList.add('fa-remove');
} }
```

But when your button is already rendered with one of these icons you can do this much easier with `toggle` function like below:

```
function start(){
  firstLiI.classList.toggle('fa-plus');
  firstLiI.classList.toggle('fa-remove');
}
```